# querySelector with `:last-of-type` returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

On [this site](https://fr.getaround.com/search?address=15%20Rue%20d%27Enghien%2C%20Paris%2C%20France&address_source=google&poi_id=&latitude=48.8718&longitude=2.3524&city_display_name=Paris&start_date=2021-03-02&start_time=06%3A30&end_date=2021-03-02&end_time=18%3A30&country_scope=FR&car_sharing=true&user_interacted_with_car_sharing=false&administrative_area=%C3%8Ele-de-France&page=2),

- The command `document.querySelector(".cobalt-Button--standalone")` returns a node.
- But the command `document.querySelector(".cobalt-Button--standalone:last-of-type")` returns null.

Why?

Comment: Because it isn't the last anchor on the page.

Comment: Is there a way to target the last element with this query selector then?

Comment: Access the last element in the return value of `document.querySelectorAll(...)`?

Comment: If that's not an option? I really need to target the last element with a CSS Selector

Comment: Well, you could use `:nth-child()`. Or assuming you always want the last element, just use `document.querySelectorAll()`, and access the last element.

Comment: may be the problem is that the elements with `cobalt-Button--standalone` class have other class values too. Thus you can use the querySelectorAll and take the last element. Remember that querySelectorAll does a pre-order traversal

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll(".cobalt-Button--standalone")].pop()` should give you what you need